# Is it possible to modify the Facebook page post via Laravel Project?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with `facebook-sdk` for the first time. I searched and found a way to share the post from the laravel project to the Facebook page. I'm using this package for sharing : `laravel-notification-channels/facebook-poster`. Now I need to edit these posts. I searched a lot but couldn't find a way. Is there a file or a path that you can suggest to me?

This is the code I use to post on the page

```
public function toFacebookPoster($product)
{
    $data = $product->title;
    $data2 = 'Buy it now: https://MY-DOMAİN/'.$product->slug;
    $data2 .= str_replace( array(','), ', #', $product->keywords);

    return (new FacebookPosterPost($data.$data2))
            ->withImage(url($product->image));
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Mentioned package ```laravel-notification-channels/facebook-poster``` only provides service to create a new post.

Comment: do you know which package I need?

Comment: if you don´t find a package, you will have to develop it on your own. after all it´s just http requests to the graph api.

Comment: I'm not that experienced :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use fb php sdk directly.
Refer doc at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post#updating

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know much about him. Can you show me something that can be an example?

Comment: this should rather be a comment than an answer

Comment: @Energy40 Read FB Graph API documentation. You have all examples there.